# How does ruby internally call any method?

Tags: ruby, oop, private

In the program below, the method of the child class calls the private method of the parent class.

```
class Parent  
  private
    def new_name
      'Private Method'
    end
end


class Child < Parent
  def get_parent_name
    puts new_name
  end
end

obj = Child.new
obj.get_parent_name
```

Ruby is said to be object oriented language so the line

```
puts new_name
```

accesses the private method of parent class. Internally, how does it call the method? As being a Object Oriented Programming Language, it should call it using an object. But an object cannot access a private method.

Comment: What is OOPS based language?

Comment: Object Oriented Programming Language

Comment: What is "S"? ........... And isn't "Object Oriented Programming Language based language" a strange phrase?

Comment: Yes sorry for the mistake. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Private methods in Ruby are inherited. So if you define private method for `Parent`, it's also present in `Child`.

Comment: Yes I know this. But if ruby is an object oriented language then internally it should call it using an object just like self. So what does it use internally?

Comment: @user3702690: implicit receiver is always `self`.

Comment: But using `self` the method is not accessible (private methods).

Comment: @user3702690: yes, private methods can't be called with explicit receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Answering you comment on the first answer.

There is an implicit reference to the current instance within the class. When you do `puts new_name` inside `get_parent_name` what you are really doing is calling `new_name` on the current instance.

Well in fact, when you say `private` what Ruby does is to avoid calling the method using an explicit object reference.

```
class Klass  
  private

  def new_name
    'Private Method'
  end

  def new_name_pub__wrong
      self.new_name  # won't work since using an explicit object reference
  end

  def new_name_pub__ok
      new_name  # will work but means basically the same as self.new_name
  end
end
```

Then in your case this is just basic OOP

Child call `new_name` on the instance (as I said above), finding none it will crawl the inheritance hierarchy and find the Parent `new_name` (private methods are visible for all sub-classes)

Comment: So means you are saying an implicit receiver is different and `self` in the same scope is different?

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you can make the receiver implicit, in which case it is implied to be `self`. This is similar to Self, Java, C#, Scala and many other object-oriented languages, and unlike Smalltalk, which always requires an explicit receiver.

Also, you seem to have no trouble at all understanding how the private `puts` method inherited from `Kernel` gets called, but there is no difference between `puts` and `new_name`, so why are you having trouble with one but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby use send to call the method. You can do it yourself and access any private method:

```
puts obj.send(:new_name)
```

[Here is the doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-send)